# Diseñador de formulario para TCL TK

Tags: python, formularios, tcl

Quería saber si alguien conoce un diseñador de formularios para TCL/TK al estilo de Qt Designer de QT.
Empecé con TkInter, y para pequeños proyectos va muy bien, pero para hacer proyectos mas grandes tipo multiventana y con muchos widgets voy a pasar mas tiempo posicionándolos y dándole atributos mediante código, que programando código funcional.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes mirarte [Pygubu](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu) y [Tkinter-Designer](https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer). No he usado ninguno, así que ni idea de si funcionan de forma aceptable con interfaces complejas. El primero seria mas similar a Glade o Qt Designer el segundo es un "traductor" para figma.com.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Estuve mirando ambos sistemas de diseño y me parece que voy a probar con Pygubu a ver que tal. El otro me parece mas complicado además de que es de pago para cosas no tan chicas. De nuevo muchas gracias.